# IOS Apps commands from another IOS app

Tags: c++, ios, windows, qt, cross-platform

I'm pretty much solely a C++/C# on Windows developer (with some Android/Unix/Linux a while ago).

I know that on Windows I can write an app that sends keyboard commands and invoke menu commands from one running executable to another.
Is this possible on IOS?
I.e.  Could I have one app invoking commands on another.  Specifically without needing a code change in the receiving app? 
E.g.  Send a hotkey to invoke a command.

Any API(s) I could look at to get started?
Could this be done with QT or would I need a Mac and XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but this is technically not possible in iOS as iOS prevents any activity from the app outside of the app. So in short your app is limited to the scope of itself and what it can do outside of its scope is very minimal (notifications, etc...)

Hope this helps!